# How to intercept dialled number using Core Telephony in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-telephony

As we know that it is possible to intercept the state of the call using below code:

```
CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

callCenter.callEventHandler=^(CTCall* call)
{

  if (call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected)
 { 

  NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");

  }

  else if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected) 
  {

NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");

  }

else if(call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
  {

   NSLog(@"Call is incoming");

  }

  else
  {

   NSLog(@"None of the conditions");

  }

};
```

**Can we intercept the dialled number by using Core Telephony framework.**

Answer (score 1):

Intercept a dialed number? If you are making the call, you already know the number right? If you meant intercept a received/incoming call and find its number, I don't think you can do that with CoreTelephony.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. What I want is to read the incoming phone number. Please help me whether its possible to read the incoming phone number in iOS using Core Telephony Framework.

Comment: Nope, sorry to inform you that you can't read incoming phone number. Core Telephony does not reveal the caller number/identification.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking the same. Many Thanks for your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

for all beginners... is ALWAYS better to read Apple API's docs, before.
This behaviour is stated clearly.